# Parâmetro inválido ao Inicializar Process() que executa o ssh do Git em Console Application do C#

Tags: c#, git

Estou tentando fazer um Console Application em C# com algumas opções de comando a serem executados no ssh do Git.
O executável ssh do Git está no seguinte caminho: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe, e estou tentando executar um simples comando da seguinte forma:

```
string pathGit = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login";
string commandString = "git";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = pathGit;
startInfo.Arguments = commandString;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

O "--login" na frente do caminho é necessário para entrar de fato no console do Git, mas é basicamente ele que está ocasionando erro. Pesquisei bastante, mas não consegui encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Não seria o correto passar o `--login` em `startInfo.Arguments`? Ou seja: `string commandString = "--login git"`.

Comment: Realmente, desta forma ele entende e entra no console. Existe a possibilidade de eu continuar utilizando esse processo para dar outros comandos daqui pra frente? (acredito que isso seria outra pergunta no site, estou certo? rs).

Comment: Claro que pode continuar passando outros parâmetros. Por isso mesmo chama-se **Arguments** :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao utilizar o [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), você deve passar os parâmetros na propriedade [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx), todos os necessários.

No seu caso, ficará assim:

```
string pathGit = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\"";
string commandString = "--login git";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = pathGit;
startInfo.Arguments = commandString;
...
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972789/git-diff-gets-stuck-when-run-as-net-process) tem um exemplo de vários parâmetros usados no [git](/questions/tagged/git).